# Expression is not a method from within a class

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am getting an error when trying to call a form from within a method:

> Expression is not a method

My code structure looks like this:

```
Public Class frmMain
      Class Server
           Private Shared Sub StringMessageReceived()
                Call frmMM() 
           End Sub
      End Class
End Class
```

How can I call the windows form within the class?

Comment: @johntotetwoo: Its just a form with a webbrowser control on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create an instance of the form, and then call its `Show` (or `ShowDialog`) method:

```
Public Class frmMain
      Class Server
           Private Shared Sub StringMessageReceived()
                Call New frmMM().Show()
           End Sub
      End Class
End Class
```

Comment: When i did that i got **ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.**

Comment: @StealthRT: And that has nothing to do with this question, so make a new one.